# General algorithm/pattern for processing text files

Tags: python, design-patterns, pseudocode

Is there a general algorithm/pattern for reading multiline text files, where some lines are dependent on preceding ones? I'm referring to data in a form like:

```
H0 //start header
HEADER1
H9 //end header   
R0 RECORD1
R0 RECORD2
H0 //start header
HEADER2
H9 //end header
R0 RECORD3
R0 RECORD4
```

Where one needs to associate the current "header" info with each following record.

I realise there are countless solutions to this sort of task, but are there tried and tested patterns that more experienced developers converge on?

EDIT:
My intuition is that one should use some sort of state machine, with states like "reading header", "reading records" etc. Am I on the right path?

EDIT: 
Although the example is simple, something that can handle higher degrees of nesting would be preferable

Answer (score 2):

This can be looked at as a parsing problem, although the grammar of the language is very simple. It is indeed [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), and thus FSM, as you correctly noted, will work. Generally speaking, any established parsing technique will work; you would avoid explicit state if using [recursive descent parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), which becomes not really recursive in case of a regular language. The following is pseudocode:

```
function accept_file:
   while not_eof
      read_line;
      case prefix of
         "H0": accept_header;
         "R0": accept_record;
         otherwise: syntax_error;

function accept_record:
   make_record from substring of current_line from position 3;

function accept_header:
   read_line;
   while current_line does not start with "H9"
      add line to accumulated_lines
   create header from accumulated_lines
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with kkm, depending on how "complex" is your grammar, you may consider using some kind of parsing lib like [ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)